# What does LOAD in nodetool status measure?

Tags: cassandra

I am observing higher load on a Cassandra node (compared to other nodes in the ring) and I am looking for help interpreting this data. I have anonymized my IPs but the snipped below shows a comparison of "good" node 199 (load 14G) and "bad" node 159(load 25G):

```
nodetool status|grep -E '199|159'
UN  XXXXX.159  25.2 GB    256          ?       ffda4798-tokentoken  XXXXXX
UN  XXXXX.199   13.37 GB   256          ?       c3a49dca-tokentoken  YYYY
```

Note load is almost 2x on .159. Yet neither memory nor disk usage explain/support this:

.199 (low load box) data -- memory at about 34%, disk 50-60G:

```
top|grep apache_cassan                                                                                                                                                    
28950 root      20   0 24.353g 0.010t 1.440g S 225.3 34.2  25826:35 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
28950 root      20   0 24.357g 0.010t 1.448g S 212.4 34.2  25826:41 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
28950 root      20   0 24.357g 0.010t 1.452g S 219.7 34.3  25826:48 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
28950 root      20   0 24.357g 0.011t 1.460g S 250.5 34.3  25826:55 apache_cassandr

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1       559G   47G  513G   9% /cassandra/data_dir_a
/dev/sdf1       559G   63G  497G  12% /cassandra/data_dir_b
/dev/sdg1       559G   54G  506G  10% /cassandra/data_dir_c
/dev/sdh1       559G   57G  503G  11% /cassandra/data_dir_d
```

.159 (high load box) data -- memory at about 28%, disk 20-40G:

```
top|grep apache_cassan   
25354 root      20   0 36.297g 0.017t 8.608g S 414.7 27.8 170:42.81 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
25354 root      20   0 36.302g 0.017t 8.608g S 272.2 27.8 170:51.00 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
25354 root      20   0 36.302g 0.017t 8.612g S 129.7 27.8 170:54.90 apache_cassandr                                                                                                                      
25354 root      20   0 36.354g 0.017t 8.625g S  94.1 27.8 170:57.73 apache_cassandr 

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1       838G   17G  822G   2% /cassandra/data_dir_a
/dev/sdf1       838G   11G  828G   2% /cassandra/data_dir_b
/dev/sdg1       838G   35G  804G   5% /cassandra/data_dir_c
/dev/sdh1       838G   26G  813G   4% /cassandra/data_dir_d
```

TL;DR version -- what does nodetool status 'load' column actually measure/report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nodetool status` command provides the following information:

- Status - U (up) or D (down)

  > Indicates whether the node is functioning or not.
- Load - updates every 90 seconds

  > The amount of file system data under the cassandra data directory after excluding all content in the snapshots subdirectories. Because all SSTable data files are included, any data that is not cleaned up, such as TTL-expired cell or tombstoned data) is counted.

For more information go to [nodetool status output description](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html#toolsStatus__description)

Comment: Thanks -- I had read this description but missed the part about "excluding snapshots". I am in fact able to get numbers close to the load by taking (total disk space used by cassandra) - (snapshot space)